# Why are the buildings built in classical style in the first half of the 19th century in Russia so frequently yellow-and-white - coloured?

Tags: russia, art, architecture, classical-antiquity, classical-greece

So many buildings built in neo-classical style in cr. 1800-1850 in Russian empire are yellow (always the same shade of yellow) with white columns. There are some exceptions, e.g. grey or blue of beige with white columns, but maybe 90-95% of buildings built in this style are yellow and white, like on the first picture.

Was this colour scheme specific to Russian Empire or was it used elsewhere?

Why was it used in the first place? Antique buildings were all white when discovered, and originally they were brightly coloured (see the example of Parthenon below), I am not aware of such pastel-with-white-details colour scheme used in the antique world (was it?)

[image: Rossi]

[image: Bourse]

[image: Church]

[image: P1]

[image: P2]

Comment: Are any of these buildings actually "painted" tho? Most look like there might be pigment in the stucco.

Comment: I will be very pedantic here and say that I have used the word "painted" when applied to Parthenon, and I believe it was made of marble then painted, no stucco involved! But certainly there were antique buildings that were covered with pigmented stucco.

Comment: I think, it is the same in Vienna and Potsdam (Sanssouci).

Comment: When I visited St Petersburg I was struck by this coloring, and mentioned to an art historian friend of mine that it reminded me of Venice as seen in the paintings by Canaletto.  The reply: this was the plan, to make the then new city be like Venice.  So an answer might be: Canaletto used yellow paint when painting Venetian buildings, and the Tsar ordered yellow paint to match Canaletto.

Comment: Are the Russian buildings actually painted?  From the pictures, it looks as though those are the colors of the actual brick/stone or other building material.  WRT the Parthenon, it (and other ancient Greek buildings) was apparently quite gaudily colored originally.  The current white is the result of a couple of thousand years of no upkeep. Do a search for "parthenon original colors".

Comment: Looking for early prominent examples, there's [Pavlovsk_Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavlovsk_Palace). I'm not seeing any obvious hints about the color though.

Comment: @kimchilover I could not find Venitian paintings of Canaletto that are particularly yellow, could you give some examples? The style is definitely Venitian though, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladian_architecture

Comment: I see https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Canaletto,_Veduta_del_Palazzo_Ducale.jpg  and https://www.rct.uk/collection/400668/the-rialto-bridge-from-the-north as predominantly lit with a yellow-ish sunlight, even though the buildings shown were probably not painted yellow as the Admiralty building in St P or the Yusupov Palace seem to be.

Comment: @kimchilover, yes, for me these colours are more beige or orange. Sansouci, as mentioned by Moishe Kogan, is the same shade of yellow (for my eye, at least).

Comment: @kimchi lover: To me, neither those Venetian buildings nor the Pavlosk Palace look like they're painted.  They seem to be the natural colors of brick or stone.  The lower part of the palace, for instance, appears to be blocks of yellowish stone laid with a white mortar.  The upper parts might be stucco colored to match the stone.  (In my experience it's quite unusual to paint brick or stone buildings.)

Comment: @jamesqf I was more after the colour, not the technology, but this is definitely an interesting development :)

Comment: Also, old buildings of Bonn university and LMU (Munchen) are also painted yellow (both were built in the early 19th century). My guess is that it was the standard paint for "official" buildings in central Europe in  the 19th century.

Comment: I heard a version that yellow ochre paint was the cheapest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These were the hallmarks of the [Rococo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rococo) style of painting and building, that originated in central Europe around the middle of the 18th century, and found its way to Russia in the early part of the 19th century. According to Wikipedia, it featured "warm pastel colours (whitish-yellow, cream-colored, pearl greys, very light blues)."

This style evolved from the "Baroque" style of the 17th century that originated in southwest Europe, and was more symmetrical and formal than Rococo. Russia was relatively late in adopting European styles, so it is the later Baroque and Rococo of central Europe, and not the earlier Baroque style of Spain that was considered the (neo) "classical" style in Russia.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am 95% convinced by your rococo theory but need to confirm with friends.
As for late adoption in Russia, I would somewhat disagree. St.Petersburg was founded in 1703, and we have many examples of early baroque (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domenico_Trezzini, St. Peter and Paul's fortress and Twelve Collegia buildings) and high baroque https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_Bartolomeo_Rastrelli ("His major works, including the Winter Palace in Saint Petersburg and the Catherine Palace in Tsarskoye Selo, are famed for extravagant luxury and opulence of decoration")

Comment: @YuliaV: I modified my answer to say that it was the later Baroque and Rococo style that was considered "classical" in Russia. My understanding is that early Baroque started in Spain, the later Baroque in Austria and Germany, and likewise the Rococo style in Central Europe. At any rate, I consider Russia as having been influenced by central Europe and not Spain.

Comment: The history (as we are taught it) says that in 1703 Peter the Great has invited the best European architects the virtually unlimited money could buy to build him a European city on what used to be a bog wasteland that belonged to Sweden. The city was planned from the beginning, many architects were from Italy, but some from France and the rest of Europe. Virtually no Russian architects in the beginning, only a few who were trained in Europe later. The only Russian-Russian building in SPb was started in 1883, and is viewed as kitsch... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_the_Savior_on_Blood